# Invalid custom hook call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm just a react beginner. I'm trying to create a custom hook, which will be triggered once an onClick event is triggered. By what I see, I need to use the useRef hook, to take into account if the component is rendered by first time, or if it's being re-rendered.

My code approach is the next:

```
const Clear = (value) => {
    const useClearHook = () => {
        const stateRef = useRef(value.value.state);
        console.log(stateRef);
        useEffect(() => {
            console.log("useEffect: ");
            stateRef.current = value.value.state;
            stateRef.current.result = [""];
            stateRef.current.secondNumber = [""];
            stateRef.current.mathOp = "";
            console.log(stateRef.current);
            value.value.setState({
                ...stateRef.current,
                result: value.value.state.result,
                secondNumber: value.value.state.secondNumber,
                mathOp: value.value.state.mathOp,
            });
        }, [stateRef.current]);
        console.log(value.value.state);
    };
    return <button onClick={useClearHook}>Clear</button>;
};
```

Any suggestion? Maybe I might not call ...stateRef.current in setState. I'm not sure about my mistake.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: This looks a bit confusing, what are you trying the achieve? What is the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `useClearHook` is not a component (the component always goes with the first capitalized letter like `UseClearHook`), so that's why when you call `useRef` in a non-component, it will throw that error. Similarly, for `useEffect`, you need to put it under a proper component.

The way you're using `state` is also not correct, you need to call `useState` instead

Here is a possible fix for you

```
const Clear = (value) => {
    const [clearState, setClearState] = useState()
    const useClearHook = () => {
        setClearState((prevState) => ({
                ...prevState,
                result: [""],
                secondNumber: [""],
                mathOp: "",
            }));
    };
    return <button onClick={useClearHook}>Clear</button>;
};
```

If your states on the upper component (outside of `Clear`). You can try this way too

```
const Clear = ({value, setValue}) => {
    const useClearHook = () => {
        setValue((prevState) => ({
                ...prevState,
                result: [""],
                secondNumber: [""],
                mathOp: "",
            }));
    };
    return <button onClick={useClearHook}>Clear</button>;
};
```

Here is how we pass it

```
<Clear value={value} setValue={setValue} />
```

The declaration for `setValue` and `value` can be like this in the upper component

```
const [value, setValue] = useState()
```

Comment: Hello Nick, thanks a lot for your time and your answer. Before reading this I already did understand all my mistakes and I achieved to fix all the mistakes and errors. Anyway, thanks so much for your help. I cannot vote the answer because I'm a new stackOverflow user. But it helps a lot. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome!~ Hope you enjoy your dev life :D @bl4ck0ut